# Unable to subscribe to topics published by Husky

Tags: ros-melodic, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm fairly confident this is a networking issue, but not sure exactly how to fix it. If I publish to a topic myself on the Husky, I can subscribe to it from a client. However, I can't subscribe to topics that the Husky creates during startup. For instance, when ssh'd into the Husky, I can use `rostopic hz /imu/data` and I see that the data is being published. However, if I do the same on the client, I don't get any information.

On the client (`~/.zshrc`), I have set the following information:

```
. /opt/ros/melodic/setup.zsh
export ROS_IP=10.10.10.115
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.10.10.111:11311
```

On the Husky (`~/.bashrc`) I have set the following:

```
. /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
export ROS_IP=10.10.10.111
```

In the Husky's `/etc/ros/setup.bash`, I have the following:

```
# Mark location of self so that robot_upstart knows where to find the setup file.
export ROBOT_SETUP=/etc/ros/setup.bash

# Setup robot upstart jobs to use the IP from the network bridge.
# export ROBOT_NETWORK=br0

# Insert extra platform-level environment variables here. The six hashes below are a marker
# for scripts to insert to this file.
######

export LCM_DEFAULT_URL=udpm://239.255.76.67:7667?ttl=5
export HUSKY_IMU_XYZ='0 -0.15 0.065'
export HUSKY_IMU_RPY='3.1415 0 0'
export HUSKY_LASER_ENABLE=1

# Pass through to the main ROS workspace of the system.
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash

# I added this in an attempt to make things work
export ROS_IP=10.10.10.111

source /home/administrator/startup_ws/devel/setup.bash
export HUSKY_LOGITECH=1
export HUSKY_JOY_DEVICE=/dev/input/js0
export HUSKY_GAZEBO_DESCRIPTION=$(rospack find husky_gazebo)/urdf/description.gazebo.xacro
```

Here are the values of various environment variables:

```
eric@cpr-mic09:~$ echo $ROBOT_NETWORK

eric@cpr-mic09:~$ echo $ROS_IP
10.10.10.111
eric@cpr-mic09:~$ echo $ROS_HOSTNAME
```

I would really appreciate any advice. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370960/unable-to-subscribe-to-topics-published-by-husky/) by [EricW](https://answers.ros.org/users/62918/ericw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like many people I struggle with this myself several times, so I eventually created a gist for setting things up correctly:
https://gist.github.com/chfritz/8c2adab45a94e091be77c55b0432ad2e

The key is to know under what name the ROS clients announce themselves to the ROS master, and making sure that all clients that want to talk to each other can resolve those names respectively.

---

Originally posted by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) with karma: 553 on 2021-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EricW](https://answers.ros.org/users/62918/ericw/) on 2021-02-03**:
Thanks so much! I'll try this out and hopefully, it fixes the issue

**Comment by [EricW](https://answers.ros.org/users/62918/ericw/) on 2021-02-03**:
Thanks for the script! It definitely is a lot cleaner than what I was using, but it's still not working for me. I'm in the same situation I was in before. I can see the ROS topics that are being published, but I can't actually get any of the messages on the client (`rostopic hz /imu/data` says no messages are coming), while when ssh'd into the client, I do get messages. I think this is an issue with the Husky's setup.

**Comment by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on 2021-02-03**:
Have you already tried the steps described in the Troubleshooting comment below the gist?

**Comment by [EricW](https://answers.ros.org/users/62918/ericw/) on 2021-02-03**:
Sorry, should have tried those and not assumed it was Husky specific. I think I'm falling into the second troubleshooting scenario you described (not able to see results of `rostopic echo /rosout` on the client). I ran `rosnode list -a` and I get `http://cpr-mic09:37661/`  for `/rosout` both while ssh'd into the Husky and while on the client. I'm not really sure how to find out what hostname the topics are actually being published on if those are matching up

**Comment by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on 2021-02-03**:
can you resolve `cpr-mic09` from the client, i.e., what happens when you ping that from the client?

**Comment by [EricW](https://answers.ros.org/users/62918/ericw/) on 2021-02-03**:
If I run `ping cpr-mic09`, I get `cpr-mic09: Name or service not known`, but if I do `ping cpr-mic09.local`, it works.

**Comment by [EricW](https://answers.ros.org/users/62918/ericw/) on 2021-02-03**:
We use a SSH configuration to connect to the robot (we call it `val`). Not sure if this could be affecting things:

```
Host val
  ForwardAgent yes
  ForwardX11 yes
  User eric
  Hostname cpr-mic09.local
```

**Comment by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on 2021-02-03**:
Well there is your problem. Like the Troubleshooting says, you have to be able to resolve all names listed by `rosnode list -a`. So either change the ROS_HOSTNAME used by the robot, or add `cpr-mic09.local` to `/etc/hosts` on the client.

**Comment by [EricW](https://answers.ros.org/users/62918/ericw/) on 2021-02-04**:
Thank you so much! I added `10.10.10.111 cpr-mic09` to `/etc/hosts` and now it works perfectly! Sorry I didn't get it from your troubleshooting instructions. I needed to lookup what `/etc/hosts` was actually doing before I realized what was happening